# Adobe reader plugin html transparent overlay

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer-11, adobe-reader

Hi Im trying to overlay a pdf, rendered using adobe-reader plugin for IE11, with a div. Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8gm54zck/2/) describing my problem. The div is positioned behind the embedded pdf for some reason. Is there a solution to this problem? The problem occours in IE11.

The pdf is embedded like this with the div below it

```
<object id="pdf">
    <embed  src="http://www.education.gov.yk.ca/pdf/pdf-test.pdf"/>
</object>
<div id="overlay" />
```

Here os the css:

```
#overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;

    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
    z-index: 1000;
}
#pdf {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 0;
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Update! I managed to make the div overlay the pdf using an iframe. But I can't make the div transparent.

```
<iframe style="position:absolute; left:0; top:0; width:150px; 
height:150px; background-color:blue; z-index:9;" src="http://www.education.gov.yk.ca/pdf/pdf-test.pdf"></iframe>

<div id="overlay" style="position:absolute; left:0; top:0; width:150px; 
height:150px; background-color:blue; z-index:10;"></div>

<iframe ALLOWTRANSPARENCY="true" style="position:absolute; left:0; top:0; width:50px; opacity: 0.0; 
height:150px; z-index:9;" 
srcdoc="<html><body style='background-color:transparent;'></body></html>"></iframe>
```

css remains the same.

A new js fiddle can be foudn [here](http://jsfiddle.net/8gm54zck/4/)

Comment: At my end, the red div is overlapping the gray pdf container.

Comment: The problem is in IE11.

Comment: This might be on to something but I need the div to be transparent too. http://jsfiddle.net/8gm54zck/3/

Comment: pablo- why is there z-index 1000?

wondering if thats the case where you have 1000 divs? which i think shouldnt be the case.

Comment: It should just be a high number. I wrote this a long time ago. I don't think the exact number matters.